# Geolocator plugin can't give me live location stream when I using " forceLocationManager: true, "

Tags: flutter, location, geolocator

Geolocator plugin can't give me live location stream when I using " forceLocationManager: true, " and I can't getting location stream in background with this code also.

**I try this code but not getting live stream**

```
Stream<Position> getLiveGeoLocatorData() {
  LocationSettings locationSettings;

  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    locationSettings = AndroidSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      distanceFilter: 50,
      forceLocationManager: true,
      //(Optional) Set foreground notification config to keep the app alive
      //when going to the background
        foregroundNotificationConfig: const ForegroundNotificationConfig(
          notificationText:
          "Example app will continue to receive your location even when you aren't using it",
          notificationTitle: "Running in Background",
          enableWakeLock: true,
        ),
    );
  } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
    locationSettings = AppleSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      activityType: ActivityType.automotiveNavigation,
      distanceFilter: 50,
      pauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically: true,
      showBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
    );
  } else {
    locationSettings = const LocationSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      distanceFilter: 100,
    );
  }

  return Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings);
}
```

**Android Permission :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

**I want... :**

1. When I set forceLocationManager: true then it's not working in foreground and background both.
2. And When I remove forceLocationManager field then it's working in only on foreground but not in background.

**I want to get live stream location in both (Foreground & Background).**